# Javascript Splitting a string into multiple object properties

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am working on a Shopify app and part of the order info that I need to get into Mongo is coming as a property that contains a single string via their API. As an example:

```js
"note": "Child 1 First Name: Ali\nChild 1 Gender: Female\nChild 1 Hair Color: Blonde\nChild 1 Hair Style: Wavy\nChild 1 Skin Tone: Tan\nChild 2 First Name: Morgan \nChild 2 Gender: Female\nChild 2 Hair Color: Brown\nChild 2 Hair Style: Ponytail\nChild 2 Skin Tone: Light\nRelationship 1 to 2: Brother\nRelationship 2 to 1: Brother\n",
```

I actually need this string to look something like this in Mongo:

```js
mongoExDoc: {
  child1FirstName: "Ali",
  child1Gender: "Female",
  child1HairColor: "Blonde",
  child1HairStyle: "Wavy",
  child1SkinTone: "Tan",
  child2FirstName: "Morgan",
  child2Gender: "Female",
  child2HairColor: "Brown",
  child2HairStyle: "Ponytail",
  child2SkinTone: "Light",
  relationship1To2: "Brother",
  relationship2To1: "Brother"
}
```

Or something along these lines. The property values themselves will NOT change. As you can see each value is separated by \n and each actual value is preceded by a:.  I would really appreciate suggestions!

Comment: let us know what you tried

Comment: string.split('\n') will get the lines.  split(' ').join('') will remove spaces.  + will allow you to concat the curly braces

Answer (score 3):

At a glance:

```js
var data = {"note": "Child 1 First Name: Ali\nChild 1 Gender: Female\nChild 1 Hair Color: Blonde\nChild 1 Hair Style: Wavy\nChild 1 Skin Tone: Tan\nChild 2 First Name: Morgan \nChild 2 Gender: Female\nChild 2 Hair Color: Brown\nChild 2 Hair Style: Ponytail\nChild 2 Skin Tone: Light\nRelationship 1 to 2: Brother\nRelationship 2 to 1: Brother\n"};

var mongoExDoc = data.note.split("\n").reduce(function(obj, str, index) {
 var strParts = str.split(":");
  obj[strParts[0].replace(/\s+/g, '')] = strParts[1];
  return obj;
}, {})

console.log(mongoExDoc);
```

Comment: This seems REALLY close! I should have mentioned that mongoExDoc is an object being created by a meteor method and had data coming from other parts of the API also. Is there a good way to (instead of building the entire object) just add each property value to a variable?

Comment: You can use `Object.assign()` to just merge the objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: When trying to log it out I am getting: 
Exception while invoking method 'getAllOrders' TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null
but when I simply log the string coming in from the API it works.

Comment: @JoethaCoder - Is that a string you have or an object? In my example, I assumed it was an object.

Comment: It is a property inside of a larger API object called customer. As an example I am getting the property like so: let data = order.customer.note;
So 'note' contains the string.

Comment: So instead of `data.note.split` - you just want `data.split` @JoethaCoder

Comment: Mind taking a look at this string with your logic? I had to use:let `rawNoteData = order.customer.note;`
      `let data = JSON.stringify(rawNoteData);`
to get: `"Child 1 First Name: Charles\nChild 1 Gender: Male\nChild 1 Hair Color: Brown\nChild 1 Hair Style: Straight\nChild 1 Skin Tone: Light\nChild 2 First Name: Audrey\nChild 2 Gender: female\nChild 2 Hair Color: brown\nChild 2 Hair Style: curly\nChild 2 Skin Tone: medium\nRelationship 1 to 2: brother\nRelationship 2 to 1: sister\n"`

Comment: The reason I ask is that your function IS spitting out objects...but they are looking pretty rough: `{ '"Child1FirstName': ' Jennifer\\nChild 1 Gender' }`

Comment: Looks like this line is double stringifying things? `let data = JSON.stringify(rawNoteData);` - what happens if you just use `let data = rawNoteData`?

Comment: That appears to be the same as simply just using rawNoteData directly. It returns the same `null` error.